# Free Software to Allow Users to Run Oracle SQL Scripts but NOT create them

Tags: sql, oracle

We would like to allow users to run custom Oracle 11G SQL scripts that have been created for them, complete with parameter prompts, and get a CSV extract of the resulting dataset.  Right now, I just use SQLPlus and SQLDeveloper to do those things, but those tools would allow the creation of custom scripts as well, and we do not want users to try to create custom queries.

In many cases we intend to fulfill this need with Crystal Reports/Crystal Server, but we use CR XI, and sometimes very WIDE extracts are difficult to create because of the page size limitations.  It also has a limit for the number of concurrent users, and sometimes we may need more.

Does anyone know of a FREE tool that can allow users to execute Oracle SQL Scripts and get file exports as a result and yet will NOT allow them to create new Scripts?

NOTE:  We have a Citrix environment and therefore are able to limit where the script files are located and what access users have to those files and folders.

Comment: If the Citrix environment is locked down, can you create a user-executable wrapper script (batch file) for each query that calls SQL*Plus to run the actual .sql script, so they don't get direct access? How are you intending to deliver the output? I think I might be missing something too...

Comment: thanks - both this idea and the one below are good.  I'll need to ponder for a bit.  As for access, we can deliver the output by having them save to their C drive and preventing saving to the server, but Justin's comment below is correct that if they could just run a text file they could lift one from their own C drive. Will ponder some more and let you know what I come up with.  Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that a SQL script is just a text file, I'm not sure I see how this could be possible but perhaps I'm missing something about how you see something like SQL*Plus allowing the creation of custom scripts.  If you give me any tool that runs SQL scripts, I can always open my favorite text editor, write a SQL script, and have your tool run it (assuming that you allow users to create new files in your Citrix environment or to map a file from their local machines).

Personally, I'd probably create a small APEX application in the database that would present a menu that let users pick an export.  Behind the scenes, the APEX app would run whatever select was necessary (I'd generally create a CLOB in the database rather than a file on the file system assuming unless you're making a great deal of use of SQL*Plus formatting commands in your scripts) and would allow the user to download the file (or use some alternate file delivery mechanism such as email).

Comment: Good point - we don't allow users to create new files from Citrix, but they could conceivably read a text file in from their C drive.  I like the APEX idea a lot.  I'm going to think on that a bit more.  I don't know if we have Oracle Application Express on our server, but looking at it, it appears to be free with the database, so I bet we could download it.

Comment: I think this looks like the way to go.  A bit more research need to ensure we can install Oracle Application Express, but so far all checks out.  And putting it in a CLOB seems to work GREAT.  I don't use much SQLPlus formatting.  And if I can set up an APEX app to run against values in a table, I avoid the text file security hole.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I use jasper reports for that: http://jasperforge.org/index.php?q=project/jasperreports